# When you say "his revenge", can "his" refer to the person on whose behalf said revenge is being taken?

Tags: possessives

Context :
Male fictional character is killed.
Female fictional character wants to seek revenge.

I've heard someone refer to said revenge as "his revenge", but to me that seems wrong and it's her revenge, and it's merely sought on his behalf.

Are there rules that define this? How is this generally used? Thanks!

Comment: If you are addressing a revenge done for another I would prefer using the word "avenge" rather than "his revenge"-- But if put into context I do not see any reason why "his revenge" would not be understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general usage it is her revenge, as you suspect. I also argue in the following way. She is the one seeking to harm another so as to gain satisfaction for the wrong done to her (loss of her friend, lover, or whatever he was). The revenge will therefore be hers. The victim is dead so he cannot harm anyone and therefore revenge cannot be his.

Comment: She could however be working on his behalf.  "Bob was dead.  But he'd seen Eve's betrayal coming, and his revenge had been planned far in advance.  The money was already in Alice's account...."

Comment: @lessthanideal Also, even if Alice is not a contract killer, she might justify her behaviour by convincing herself that she truly has a duty to carry Bob's revenge on his behalf, rather than admit that she's seeking revenge for herself. This might be reflected in the narration by having other characters saying "Alice's revenge", but Alice herself saying "avenging Bob" or "Bob's revenge" and never "my revenge".

Comment: Aaaaand now I see that once more, the algorithms of stackexchange have tricked me into commenting on a years-old question while I thought I was browsing recent questions.

Comment: @Stef it's a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic assumptions are wrong:

Male fictional character is killed. Female fictional character wants to seek *vengeance*. Killing his killer will *avenge* his death, or be an act of *revenge* (the specific act which "balances the scales", not the general need for redressal).

It's misused so often that your meaning is perfectly clear anyway.

Anyway, **the act is hers so the revenge is hers**. The vengeance and revenge are *for* his death.

If she were somehow acting as his agent in a way that made it *his action*, then it could be his revenge. This is an unusual use, and only really makes sense (for example) in a context where he had some elaborate plan for after his death.